# Bid price... sudden Drop

Tags: call-options, option-exercise

I have a call option that is 45 day out from expiration. The stock price is sitting at about twice my strike price.
Why did my bid price dropped from $2.00 to .10 in one day?

Is my only option now to exercise option buy shares low and sell at market?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option gives you the option rather than the obligation to buy (or sell) the underlying so you don't have to exercise you can just let the option expire (so long it doesn't have an automatic expiry). After expiration the option is worthless if it is out of the money but other than that has no hangover.

Option prices normally drop as the time value of the option decays. An option has two values associated with it; time value and exercise value. Far out of the money (when the price of the underlying is far from the strike price on the losing side) options only have time value whereas deep in the money options (as yours seems to be) has some time value as well as the intrinsic value of the right to buy (sell) at a low (high) price and then sell (buy) the underlying.

The time value of the option comes from the possibility that the price of the underlying will move (further) in your favour and make you more money at expiry. As expiry closes it is less likely that there will be a favourable mood so this value declines which can cause prices to move sharply after a period of little to no revaluing.

Up to now what I have said applies to both OTC and traded options but exchange traded options have another level of complexity in their trading; because there are fewer traders in the options market the size of trade at which you can move the market is much lower. On the equities markets you may need to trade millions of shares to have be substantial enough to significantly move a price, on the options markets it could be thousands or even hundreds. If these are European style options (which sounds likely) and a single trading entity was holding a large number of the exchange traded options and now thinks that the price will move significantly against them before expiry their sell trade will move the market lower in spite of the options being in the money. Their trade is based on their supposition that by the time they can exercise the option the price will be below the strike and they will lose money. They have cashed out at a price that suited them and limited what they will lose if they are right about the underlying.

If I am not correct in my excise style assumption (European) I may need more details on the trade as it seems like you should just exercise now and take the profit if it is that far into the money.

Comment: One more additional layer of complexity. Often equity exchange traded options have a market maker (often the underwriter of the option itself). When issuing a new equity exchange traded option, the underwriter will set a total number options to issue (limits risk). The market maker must have a reasonable bid/ask spread at all times. Which stops the market maker reducing the price to zero (offering to sell options for free is bad business). EXCEPT in the case when they "run out of stock" (can't sell something when there are zero units left in inventory) at which point the market maker might set